# What is the right way to inject variables into release pipeline while deploying Azure app service for containers?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, devops

I am new to Docker/Container deployment and struggling to find a way to inject variables during the release pipeline(CD).

For normal app service the approach was to take variables and transform using a task like this one(below picture) in Azure Devops. But **in this scenario there was an artifact generated from the build pipeline** and we could change in the artifact generated.

[image]

But since in the docker approach, after build we will pushing the image into a [Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/container-registry/), how do we inject variables for different environments?

1. Are there any guide blogs explaining the process for the same?
2. Is injecting variables during the release pipeline the best approach? Or should we inject during the build pipeline?